# Сменить местоположение файла подкачки Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Файлы подкачки "едят" непозволительно много места на системном диске (С:). Сама студия установлена на другом диске, но файлы подкачки (в т.ч. и для `gradle`) принципиально создаются на C:

Есть возможность перенести директории с файлами на другой диск/путь?

В настройках/интернете решение не нашел.

Вот как выглядят папки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не "файлы подкачки", а служебные файлы.

Comment: @Эникейщик, да.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не факт что мое мнение верное, но изменение файла подкачки может привести к некоторым проблемам в работе студии, но думаю что попробовать изменить местоположение можно.

В Windows, Android Studio по умолчанию складывает SDK / Gradle папки в папку профиля пользователя, в итоге общий вес папок может быть очень объемным, что как минимум может привести к перезаполнению жесткого диска, что нужно сделать для переноса:

- Скопировать папки `%appdata%\local\Android\Sdk и %userprofile%\.gradle` в другое место, например `d:\Android`
- Настроить переменные окружения:

  set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
  %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
- Далее открыть Android Studio перенастроить параметры SDK - File > Settings... > A[[erance & Behavior > Systemc Settings > Android SDK
- Перенастроить параметры Gradle - File > Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle изменить параметр Service directory path

[Environment variables](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/variables) ссылка на документацию.

[Первоисточник](https://forum.sys-adm.in/index.php?topic=5709.0).

Comment: @Jarvis_J, попробуйте сейчас, вроде должна работать нормально

Comment: то, что надо. Спасибо

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: Ок, сейчас подправлю ответ, ссылку я так понял указывать просто как первоисточник?

Comment: @Uranus, я исправил ответ.

Answer (score 8):

Папки `.AndroidStudioX.X`  и `.gradle` занимают не очень много места. Основной объем занимает папка `.android` - в ней хранятся образы виртуальных устройств, а каждый из них может быть размером по 2-3 гигабайта. И если создано несколько эмуляторов на разные SDK и размеры экранов, то папка может быстро разрастись до десятка-двух гигабайт. Поэтому

***Частичное решение:*** (для папки `.android`)

***Вариант 1 – сжать***

Эту папку можно сжать. Ее размер на диске уменьшится раза в четыре (для примера - три AVD общим размером 8 Гб после сжатия занимают на диске меньше 2 Гб), на загрузке виртуальных устройств это не скажется.

*Правый клик на папке -> Свойства -> вкладка "Общие" -> Дополнительно -> Поставить галочку "Сжать содержимое"*

***Вариант 2 – перенести***

Правый клик на *Компьютер -> Свойства -> Дополнительные параметры системы -> вкладка "Дополнительно" -> Переменные среды ->* создать системную переменную `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` со значением, например, `D:\Android`. В Андроид Студии ничего настраивать не надо. Когда Менеджер AVD будет запущен, то он создаст  по адресу `D:\Android` папку `.android` и все новые эмуляторы будут по умолчанию создаваться там. Можно перенести туда уже имеющиеся эмуляторы.

***Вариант 3 – перенести и сжать***

Совмещает достоинства Варианта 1 (освобождается место на диске С) и Варианта 2 (значительно снижается занимаемое на диске место).